# Slice N elements from middle of array

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I want to slice 5 elemtens from an array, giving a middle index:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Examples:

- Index: [0] => Return: `[1,2,3,4,5]`
- Index: [3] => Return: `[2,3,4,5,6]`
- Index: [5] => Return: `[4,5,6,7,8]`
- Index: [9] => Return: `[6,7,8,9,10]`

I tried to extract left and right parts.

```
$i = 0 // selected index
$right = array_slice($a,$i,2);
$left = array_slice($a,$i-2,2);
$index = $a[$i];
```

But it doesn't work when reaches the end (both sides).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an upper and lower bound with `max/min`

```
$right = array_slice($a,min($i,count($a)),2);
$left = array_slice($a,max(0,$i-2),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you're after:

```
$ary = range(1, 10);
$len = 5;

for($index = 0; $index < 10; $index++) {
    $start = min(count($ary) - $len, max(0, $index - ($len >> 1)));
    $slice = array_slice($ary, $start, $len);
    echo $index, ":", implode(",", $slice), "\n";
}
```